# Passing a vector or arguments to boost::process (boost::fusion)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion, boost-process

I'm trying to create a `boost::process` from a vector of string arguments:

```
void runProcess( const std::string& exe, const std::vector<std::string>& args )
{
    bp::ipstream out;
    bp::child c(exe, args, std_out > out);
    ...
}
```

This apparently works, but I'm getting the following warning:

> warning C4503: 'boost::fusion::detail::for_each_linear': decorated name length exceeded, name was truncated

It diseappears if passing arguments one by one `bp::child c(exe, "param1", "param2", std_out > out);`.

What is the correct way to call `child`constructor in this situation?

Comment: You are using it correctly. May want to read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/074af4b6.aspx

Comment: @StoryTeller: Thanks, but it's unclear to me how the example provided by Microsoft could help removing the warning in my case....what would be the "no warning syntax"? (I have a requirement to have code compile with no warning, and we always prefer to avoid disabling a warning, even locally).

Answer (score 8):

You would use the as intended:

```
bp::child c(bp::search_path("ls"), bp::args({"-1", "-l"})/*, ...*/);
```

In your case maybe like

```
void runProcess( const std::string& exe, const std::vector<std::string>& args )
{
    bp::ipstream out;
    bp::child c(exe, bp::args(args), std_out > out);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Using `bp::args` does not prevent the warnings from being reported.

Comment: Oh.  These should simply be reported to the library devs. Try `#include <boost/disable_warnings.hpp>` IIRC

Comment: Done: https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/13323#ticket. Thanks for the help